# Python. Не могу понять суть задания

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Отсортировать двухмерный ndarray по возрастанию значения суммы по столбцу. А затем исключить максимальный элемент в каждом столбце и повторить сортировку.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2, 3))
print(a)
print()

a.sort(axis=0)
print(a, "\n", type(a))
print()

d = a.max(axis=0)
print(d)
```

Как я понял, если, конечно, это правильно, то нужно отсортировать по столбцу, а потом найти максимальный элемент и как-то удалить из массива.

Comment: Написано же "по возрастанию значения суммы по столбцу". Что такое "сумма по столбцу" вам понятно, нет?

Comment: как раз не особо, что такое сумма по столбцу, мне что ли нужно было до всех манипуляций с сортировкой, сделать сложение чисел в массиве, например - [[1+2, 3+4, 5+6], [7+8, 1+5, 5+5]], суммировать их и сделать сортировку по возрастанию значения суммы

Comment: Ну скорее всего самому делать не надо, надо сказать `numpy`, чтобы он при сортировке учитывал эти суммы. А откуда у вас 12 значений, если массив 2х3? Если без учёта этого, то да, как-то так.

Comment: 6 значений в результате суммирования

Comment: У вас всего 6 значений в массиве исходно `size=(2, 3)`

Comment: Не я имею ввиду, что если выполнить сумму в этих массивах - [[1+2, 3+4, 5+6], [7+8, 1+5, 5+5]], то в результате у нас появится 6 чисел, по 3 числа в каждом массиве, в итоге будет 2x3 массив, после чего можно уже двигаться дальше

Comment: Я не понимаю, у вас изначально массив какой? `a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(2, 3))`

Comment: Да, но то что выше мною написано, просто догадки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку это учебное задание, готовый вариант ответа давать не спортивно. Но я вам покажу <s>откуда готовилось нападение</s> какие функции можно использовать:

- `a.sum(axis=...)` - для получения суммы по строкам/столбцам (в зависимости от `axis`)
- `a.sort(axis=...)` - для сортировки строк/колонок
- `np.argsort(...)` - для получения порядка сортировки значений
- `a[...:...]` - для получения среза данных с нужным диапазоном и/или порядком индексов

Вам просто нужно применить эти методы с подходящими аргументами и использовать их в нужном порядке.

Но так то суть задания в том, чтобы сначала взять суммы по столбцам и отсортировать столбцы по значениям этих сумм (в каком порядке они идут, тут и пригодится `argsort`). А затем выкинуть максимумы по столбцам и сделать сортировку ещё раз. Выкинуть максимумы на мой взгляд проще всего через сортировку + срез (взять от отсортированного для этого массива все строки, кроме строки с максимумами).